# MySQL SELECT MAX of SUM() values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, max

I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) AS total_days,
    scp.cpl_startdate
FROM
    studentcourseplanelements scpe
        INNER JOIN
    studentcourseplan scp ON scp.cpl_id = scpe.scpe_cpl_id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        sd1.student_id, sd1.student_startdate
    FROM
        studentdates sd1
    WHERE
        sd1.student_id = '360'
    LIMIT 1) sd ON sd.student_id = scp.student_id
GROUP BY scp.cpl_id
```

This outputs:

```
+------------+---------------+
| total_days | cpl_startdate |
+------------+---------------+
|          5 | 2012-11-01    |
|        129 | 2012-11-02    |
+------------+---------------+
```

I want to select only the row with highest `total_days`, in my example 129.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will show duplicate records having highest `total_days`, eg

```
+------------+---------------+
| total_days | cpl_startdate |
+------------+---------------+
|          5 | 2012-11-01    |
|        129 | 2012-11-02    |  <= shown
|        129 | 2012-11-03    |  <= shown
+------------+---------------+
```

query

```
SELECT  SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) AS total_days,
        scp.cpl_startdate
FROM    studentcourseplanelements scpe INNER JOIN studentcourseplan scp
            ON scp.cpl_id = scpe.scpe_cpl_id
        INNER JOIN
        (SELECT  sd1.student_id, sd1.student_startdate
         FROM    studentdates sd1
         WHERE   sd1.student_id = '360'
         LIMIT 1) sd ON sd.student_id = scp.student_id
GROUP BY scp.cpl_id
HAVING SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(total_days)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) AS total_days,
            FROM    studentcourseplanelements scpe INNER JOIN studentcourseplan scp 
                         ON scp.cpl_id = scpe.scpe_cpl_id
                    INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT  sd1.student_id, sd1.student_startdate
                     FROM    studentdates sd1
                     WHERE   sd1.student_id = '360'
                     LIMIT 1) sd ON sd.student_id = scp.student_id
            GROUP BY scp.cpl_id
        ) s
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding `ORDER BY total_days DESC LIMIT 0,1`

This will sort by most, and only return the top answer.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, you and Stephen both provided me with the same answer and since you were indeed first I will mark this as an answer. However I have to wait another 9 minutes to do so :)

Comment: yep you're first but i have a question, what if you have two records which has the same `total_days`? eg `5, 2012-01-01`, `10, 2012-01-02`,`10, 2012-01-03` ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to order it by the SUM column descending, and then get the first record listed. 
Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) AS total_days,
    scp.cpl_startdate
FROM
    studentcourseplanelements scpe
        INNER JOIN
    studentcourseplan scp ON scp.cpl_id = scpe.scpe_cpl_id
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        sd1.student_id, sd1.student_startdate
    FROM
        studentdates sd1
    WHERE
        sd1.student_id = '360'
    LIMIT 1) sd ON sd.student_id = scp.student_id
ORDER BY SUM(scpe.scpe_estemated_days) DESC
GROUP BY scp.cpl_id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! However `GROUP BY` comes before `ORDER BY` :)

Comment: what if you have two records which has the same total_days? eg `5, 2012-01-01`, `10, 2012-01-02`,`10, 2012-01-03` ?